# knox gateway on hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, knox-gateway

I have installed knox server and done all the steps mentioned on hortonworks site.
When i ran the below command on the sandbox , it gives me the proper output.

```
curl http://sandbox:50070/webhdfs/v1?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY
```

Now i have another VM running fedora . I am assuming it as external client and trying to do external access but getting no output:-

```
 curl -k https://<sandbox-ip>:8443/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY
```

Can someone point me whats wrong with my settings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your topology but if you are using the default one (sandbox) you probably need to add basic auth e.g.

```
curl -k -u guest:guest-password -X GET https://<sandbox-  ip>:8443/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY
```

Also check the logs at

```
<knox_install>/logs/gateway.log
```

They should tell you more about what went wrong.

Good luck !

Comment: ..it helped..but have one question..once knox is running why the dafault login is still working..!connect jdbc:hive2://sandbox:10001/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice...ideally it should not..all traffic should go over knox...or i need to enable something at hive server2..

Comment: Glad it worked ! the reason your default login (I am assuming you mean direct connection) works is because you need to lock it down by preventing connections other than Knox.

Comment: ..yes i mean direct connection via port 10001 ..without user and password ...by locking what you mean...and what methods...

Comment: Make sure you enabled demo LDAP server for knox